# MySQL Workbench - How to write a script to delete a connection?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I currently have MySQL Workbench 8.0.33 (and tried .34) and in both cases, I have a database connection that is corrupted.  When I attempt to click "delete" on it, MySQL Workbench closes down. But when I re-open the application, that bad connection is still on the list.

Is there a way I can write and execute a simple MySQL workbench script that will delete this specific connection? I see the following area, which leads to my curiosity...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by taking a different approach through the following steps:

- Made a back up of my connections from within MySQL Workbench
- Extracted that zip file, and removed the faulty connection, and re-zipped the files up again. Named it **good_connections.zip**
- Used MySQL Installer to uninstall Workbench (without completely uninstalling Installer)
- Went into my AppData/Roaming/MySQL/Workbench/ directory and modified the connections.xml file and the server_instances.xml file, to remove the faulty connection.
- Used MySQL Installer to install the latest version of Workbench again.
- Opened up Workbench under this new installed process, and restored my backup connections with the previous **good_connections.zip** I made.

Done.